# How to upload file using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

Below is my selenium code

```
selenium.type("document.forms['UploadForm'].elements['browse']",file.getAbsolutePath());
selenium.click("document.forms['UploadForm'].elements['submit']");
```

I have multiple forms,which has multiple browse button with property as "broswe" an d multiple submit buttons with property as submit.Since am uploading file by using the form name where i  need to upload the file,i.e "UploadForm" and need to submit in the same form.

But the problem am facing is with out uploading the file,selenium is hitting submit button.

Below is autoit script

```
WinWaitActive("Choose File")
Send("C:\Work\selenium\PMG_SPRINT_AUTOMATION\pmg_automation\block_PTN.csv")   
Send("{ENTER}")
```

How do i adjust this code in my selenium class as there are multiple selenium buttons

```
try {
  String[] commands = new String[]{};
  commands = new String[]{"C:\\Program Files\\AutoIt3\\attachDocScript.exe"}; //location of the autoit executable
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
       }
  catch (IOException e) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with Autoit.There you can write script for uploading and downloading documents very easily and then you can call those scripts in your selenium code wherever needed.

Comment: This link might be useful to u
 http://automationtricks.blogspot.in/2010/09/how-to-upload-file-in-selenium-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using right logic only. For uploading file you need to type the content(file absolute path) in browse area without clicking on that and then click on submit to upload that file.

Even though you have multiple browse buttons you can specific one by using index or specfic locator.

[image]

Eg:

```
selenium.type("//span[@id='attach1']/input","/home/test/file1.csv");
selenium.type("//span[@id='attach2']/input","/home/test/file2.csv");
selenium.type("//span[@id='attach3']/input","/home/test/file3.csv");
.
.
selenium.click("submit");
```

Comment: I have multiple browse  buttons with same name but different forms.then how do i do it?

Comment: selenium.type("//span[@id='document.forms['bulkUnBlockUploadForm'].elements['requestFile']']/input",file.getAbsolutePath());   //even this syntax change does not work

Answer (score 0):

1. Create AutoIT script for multiple file upload

   ```
   WinWaitActive("Open"); Name of the file upload window
   Send(' C:\Users\himanichaudhary\Desktop\"Capture1.PNG" "stop.jpg" "image3" image4"');
   Send("{ENTER}")
   ```
2. Save and Compile the script to create "exe"
3. Use `Process.start("D:\\Users\\MultiFileUpload.exe");` (Path of file where AutoIt exe is located in double slash format) in C# code.**

   or

   ```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Path of file where autoIt script in exe is located");`
   ```